# I wrote a string conversion function in the androidJNI C layer. It can run correctly under DEBUG. When I compressed it into an APK file. It cannot run

Tags: c

I wrote a string conversion function in the android JNI C layer. It can run correctly under DEBUG. When I compressed it into an APK file. It cannot run. And report an error,I don't understand where the problem is. There is no confusion at the JNI layer. When I don't call this function, the apk can run normally. Otherwise, this function can run normally only in DEBUG mode

```
char *ove(char *str, size_t len) {

    char *start = str;
    char *end = str + len - 1;
    char ch;

    if (str != NULL) {
        while (start < end) {
            ch = *start;
            *start++ = *end;
            *end-- = ch;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

```
char test(char *msg) {
    char letter[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
    char number[] = "0123456789";
    char *data = ove(msg, strlen(msg));
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++) {
        char a = data[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(letter); j++) {
            char b = letter[j];
            char c = number[j];
            if (isalpha(a) != 0) {
                if (strcmp(&a, &b) == 0) {
                    sprintf(cryptograph, "%s%s", cryptograph, &c);
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (strcmp(&a, &c) == 0) {
                    sprintf(cryptograph, "%s%s", cryptograph, &b);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    LOGE("JNILOG_%s", cryptograph)
}
```

this is error msg

```
#06 pc 00000000002ea530  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, _jobject*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+3192)
#43 pc 00000000003f0c24  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52)
#51 pc 0000000000363748  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+652)
#52 pc 00000000000bd920  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+116)
```

Comment: How can this code possibly work? sprintf("...%s", ..., &c) expects c to be a zero-terminated string. That is not necessarily the case. Likewise, you can't pass simple chars to strcmp and expect things to work. Read up on the difference between C chars and char arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, this code is confusing C arrays and characters.

You need to change (at a minimum) the following:

- `strcmp(&a, &b) == 0` should be `a == b`
- `sprintf(cryptograph, "%s%s", cryptograph, &c);` should be `sprintf(cryptograph, "%s%c", cryptograph, c);` OR just `cryptograph[i+x] = c;` (where x is the length of cryptograph at the start of the function)

Comment: After your help. It can already run normally in APK files. thank you very much. I am not good at C. But I am very puzzled. Why I can run it directly in Android Studio. It only revealed the problem when I packaged it into an APK.

Comment: The environment (cpu architecture, memory layout,...) is completely different between the android studio emulator and a real device. In both cases your code is packaged into an APK,though.

Comment: I am directly connected to the device and run on a real device. Not a virtual machine. There are many differences between virtual machines and real devices. I know this, so I mostly use real devices for debugging. Yes. Direct operation should also be an APK. But when I package and install it separately. It will not function properly. It can run when connected to AndroidStudios directly with real devices. I am very confused.